# Text overflow when a room is both frozen and read only in new chat mobile design

Tags: bug, chat, design, mobile-web

The [CoGro Musings chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/838/cogro-musings) is read only (employees only) and very often frozen, as it is right now.

The full site theme shows only:

> This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.

Which is fine, however this is what I saw in the new mobile chat design when viewing on my mobile device: (LG G3)

> [image]

I was not able to reproduce on a desktop computer with the mobile theme, only on mobile device.

Full details: LG G3, Android 5.0, Chrome 49